# Set header for specific folder (.htaccess)

Tags: php, .htaccess

For some reason, Google is indexing some of my pages that are called via AJAX and return JSON data for my website. Those pages aren't meant to be visited so I don't want them to appear on Search.

so, in `.htaccess`, I'm trying to set a header for a particular folder that holds all the AJAX files.
I've tried both

```
<Files ~ "ajax\.php$">
  Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"
</Files>
```

and

```
<Files ~ "\ajax\.php$">
  Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"
</Files>
```

but none of those seem to work.

```
<Files ~ "\.php$">
  Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"
</Files>
```

however works, but then all my php pages get this header, which is not what I'm looking for of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the `<Directory>` tag to add it only to files in the `ajax` directory and then do `<FilesMatch>` to add it to `.PHP` files only.

```
<Directory "/ajax">
   <FilesMatch "\.php$">
        #put your header set stuff here
        Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"
   </FilesMatch>
</Directory>
```

Check out this link for some more help.
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#examples

Comment: Just a footnote that `<Directory..>` tag isn't allowed in `.htaccess` though OP has tagged question as `.htaccess`. `<Directory ..>` has to be used in Apache server config or vhost files only.

Answer (score 0):

You may use it like this:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "ajax\.php$" ROBOTAG
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow" env=ROBOTAG
```