# How to send cache-control header to browser for all images in /public folder in laravel?

Tags: .htaccess, http, caching, browser-cache

I have some images (`.png`) in `/public` folder, I want to send `Cache-Control` header to the browser.

I am using laravel 9, php 8.2, and sail.

My `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 10 days"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "(gif|ico|jpeg|jpe|jpg|svg|png|css|js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

It didn't work, any solutions?

Comment: A webserver can't _force_ a browser to do anything - it has no control at all over the client side. It can only give out information about what it'd _like_ it to do, based on established protocols. In this case you can tell it it's _allowed_ to cache them (simply by implication of not telling it _not_ to cache them), but I don't think there's a header you can set which explicitly says it _should_ cache them. in practice, most browsers will automatically cache such files unless you specifically tell them not to via the cache-control and related headers, but in theory a user could turn that off.

Comment: @ADyson I know, but I meant how to send `Cache-control` header, which says: allow browser to cache this file for X time. but I'm not sure how to send it to the client when he requests an image in /public directory

Comment: Please [edit] the question to ask what you actually meant to ask, then :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set header for specific folder (.htaccess)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57753717/set-header-for-specific-folder-htaccess)

Comment: You won't be able to use the solution with `<Directory>` from the mentioned duplicate (because that directive is not available in .htaccess) - but https://stackoverflow.com/a/57754813/1427878 should work.

Comment: @CBroe For some reason the .htaccess itself doesn't do anything, even when I add anything.